# Spring 4 using class based database initialization instead of xml bean

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

In our Spring 4 application, we currently configure database connection in applicationContext.xml :

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="springHikariCP" />
    <property name="dataSourceClassName" value="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />

    <property name="dataSourceProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:postgresql://google/mydb?cloudSqlInstance=project:region:myinstance&amp;socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory</prop>
            <prop key="user">postgres</prop>
            <prop key="password">password</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Instead on defining this in applicationContext.xml, can I define the database configuration in a class such as the following:

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
config.setJdbcUrl(JDBC_URL);
config.setUsername(DB_USER);
config.setPassword(DB_PASS);
....
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Have you read the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java), which explains all that in great detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can define properties on [HikariDataSource](https://static.javadoc.io/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.6.3/com/zaxxer/hikari/HikariDataSource.html)

```
public DataSource getDataSource(){ 
   HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
   dataSource.setJdbcUrl(JDBC_URL);
   dataSource.setUsername(DB_USER);
   dataSource.setPassword("DB_PASS);
   return dataSource;
}
```

> ```
> public class HikariDataSource extends HikariConfig implements DataSource, Closeable
> ```

Then declare your method as a `@Bean` in `@Configuration` class

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceClass.getDataSource();
}
```

Comment: But how would the application context detect this? Where should this be defined? Does it mean I have to just remove the xml bean code and add a java class with HikariDataSource code?

Comment: @user5155835 how do you getconnection now? you can getConnection from `dataSource`

Comment: @user5155835 you can write Datasource creation logic in a method and annotate that method with {@Bean} annotation, and you an auto wire Datasource in other classes

Comment: @user7294900 I'm using JPA Hibernate. So I don't do getconnection. I'm confused as to what annotations do I have to put in the class where I'll be defining HikariDataSource

Comment: @RaviTeja I'm using JPA Hibernate

Comment: @user5155835 Updated, basically declare your method as a `@Bean` in `@Configuration` class

Answer (score 0):

This is a king of more general solution, not specific for your DataSource but it can be useful:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:test");
        dataSourceBuilder.username("SA");
        dataSourceBuilder.password("");
        return dataSourceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

What you actually need is a DataSource bean (in XML you define a bean right?) and also put it into `@Configuration` class so the Spring could pick it up.

What you put in that method should return pre-configured for your specific case data source.

Also, you could try something like this:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig("/hikari.properties");
    HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);

    return dataSource;
}
```

But then you need `hikari.properties` file in the classpath. Example:

```
driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDb
connectionTestQuery=SELECT 1
maximumPoolSize=20
username=...
password=...
```

Remember to keep `@Bean` in `@Configuration` :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply annotate a class with `@Configuration`, making sure that this class is scanned by Spring when the application starts.
Within this class declare a datasource as `@Bean` in this way:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

// More code...

    @Bean(name="datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {

        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();

        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://....");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("postgres");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("password");
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(30000);
        hikariConfig.setPoolName("springHikariCP");

        HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);

        return hikariDataSource;    

    }

// More code...

}
```

And that's all.